# Bass-Serre tree of Isom($\mathbb{Z}$)

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, free-groups

I wish to **draw** the Bass-Serre tree associated to Isom($\mathbb{Z}$). Now I'll be honest, I'm not absolutely certain what a Bass-Serre tree is, but this is in the context of amalgamated free products, so I'll work from the wiki definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bass%E2%80%93Serre_theory#Amalgamated_free_product). So how do we work through this? Do we look at both reflection and translation as isometries on $\mathbb{Z}$ and use this?

Comment: Do you know how to write the group $Isom(\mathbb{Z})$ as free product?

Comment: Yes, if we generate Isom($\mathbb{Z}$) by $s(k):=k+1$ and $t(k):=-k+1$ and note that for the reflection $r(k):=-k$, we get $s=tr$. Then Isom($\mathbb{Z}$)=$ \langle x,t\rangle $, a presentation is then $\langle r,t\mid r^2=t^2=1\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 * \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bass-Serre tree of a free product $G=A\ast B$ is a tree equipped with a specific action of $G$. There are two types of vertices - red vertices and blue vertices. No two vertices of the same colour are incident.

Red vertices correspond to the group $A$, and incident edges are labelled by elements of $A$. The group $A$ acts on the tree by fixing some red vertex $v_A$ and permuting the incident edges (and the corresponding rooted trees) using the right-action (say) of $A$ on the labelling. Every red vertex is fixed by some conjugate of $A$, and every conjugate fixes some red vertex.

Identically, blue vertices correspond to the group $B$, and incident edges are labelled by elements of $B$. The group $B$ acts on the tree by fixing some blue vertex $v_B$ and permuting the incident edges (and the corresponding rooted trees) using the right-action (say) of $B$ on the labelling. 
Every blue vertex is fixed by some conjugate of $B$, and every conjugate fixes some red vertex.

Note that edges are labelled by both $A$ and $B$ - a labelling for each end of the edge. If this was a free product with amalgamation, the action of $A$ and $B$ on the tree would fix certain edges.

Note that the quotient of this tree by the action of your group $G$ is a graph of groups. This is why we say that "$G$ is the fundamental group of a graph of groups" (the Bass-Serre acts like the universal cover.)

In your example, as you showed in the comments, both $A$ and $B$ are cyclic of order two. Therefore, each vertex has precisely *two* incident edges. Which trees do you know where every vertex has degree precisely two?!?

Comment: Well it's an infinite path expanding both left and right, if laid out horizontally. But help me out here: the vertex set is the disjoint union of cosets, do we then join the branches at the identity $1_r \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $1_t \mathbb{Z}_2$ since the identities are equal and then pathing outwards is doing a rotation or translation?
If we have $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_4*_{\mathbb{Z}_2}\mathbb{Z}_6$, should I then expect vertices with 4 and 6 incident edges?

Comment: Exactly - its just looks like $\mathbb{Z}$. How does the action of $A$ differ from the action of $B$?

Comment: For $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, the amalgamation changes things: you want $4/2=2$ and $6/2=3$ incident edges (this is the number of cosets).

Comment: I'm assuming the action of A is rotation and B is translation, is that not correct?

Comment: No. Traslation has infinite order. The action is described in my post - it is right multiplication on the edge labels. For example, if the edges incident to $V_B$ are labelled $b$ and $1_b$ (where $b^2=1_b$) then...what?

Comment: ah yes, I mean this guy $t(k)=-k+1$. Judging by what you said on right multiplication the edges flip (permute) by applying $b$ again, since $b^2=1_b$.