# Examples of non-free group actions on trees with finite edge-stabilizers

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, trees, geometric-group-theory

I am interested in finding examples of finitely-generated non-free groups $H$ such that $H$ is a finite index subgroup of some group $G$ and $H$ acts without edge-inversion on some tree $T$ with finite edge-stabilizers. I am unsure what sort of constraints can be placed on $H$ in this context. I am familiar with Bass-Serre Theory but I am still new to it.

I would also be interested in the case that $H$ is free but its action on $T$ is not.

Any ideas/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there any constraints on $G$? Otherwise, the condition that $H$ has finite index in $G$ tells us nothing. As currently written, free products act on trees with trivial (hence finite) edge stabilisers, so these answer the question: take $H$ to be your favourite free product of non-free groups.

Comment: Free products also give examples of non-free actions of free groups: if $F$ is a free group then $F\ast F$ is free, but acts non-freely on the associated Bass-Serre tree.

Comment: your comment seems unfinished. Is there....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, free products give you actions on trees with the properties you desire.

1. If $A$ or $B$ are non-free groups then the free product $A*B$ acts on its Bass-Serre tree with trivial (hence finite) edge stabilisers.
2. If $A$ and $B$ are free groups then the free product $A*B$ is free but acts non-freely on its Bass-Serre tree (as vertex stabilisers are non-trivial).

I wrote out a description of the Bass-Serre tree for a free product $A*B$ and the associated action [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2629740/10513).

More exotic examples can be cooked up using HNN-extensions or free products with amalgamation (e.g. finite but non-trivial edge stabilisers in (1)).

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. As you say, this completely answers the question in terms of the group action, as there are no real constraints on $G$. My interest now would be to find groups which contain these free products as finite-index subgroups in a "non-trivial" way. For example, of course we can add a generator to $H$ which commutes with the others and this will yield a group $G$ with $[G:H] =2$, but i deem this as a "trivial extension" (not entirely rigorous of course) since an action of $G$ on $T$ can easily seen as being induced by the action of $H$. Perhaps this deserves its own question...

Comment: @jonan Yes, this new question is more interesting and deserves a new question. (Note that you could also add a new generator of order $2$ which permutes the free factors, so you have a semidirect product as well as a direct product with the properties you're after). Possibly the assumption you want is for $G$ to have "Serre's property FA", which means every action on a tree is, in a sense, trivial (there is a global fixed point). For example, triangle groups have FA, but have a finite-index subgroup which does not.

Comment: If you're interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4101989/extending-groups-by-finite-index-in-a-non-trivial-way

Comment: @jonan You should link to this question there, so that people better understand your motivation and can give you a better answer.