# Extending groups by finite index in a non-trivial way

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

For any group $H$ and any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it is always possible to find a group $G$ which contains $H$ as an $n$-index subgroup. For example, we can simply add a single generator $x$ to $H$ which commutes with the generators of $H$ and which has order $n$. In this simple case, one transversal takes the form $\{1, x, ... , x^{n-1}\}$ which forms a multiplicative set.

Given a group $H$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, can we always define relations on the formal elements $\{g_1, ... , g_n\}$ so that $G = g_1H \sqcup ... \sqcup g_nH$ forms a group and that $\{g_1, ... , g_n\}$ isn't multiplicative? How about if we force $H = J*K$?

And finally, what about $H\subseteq G$ which admit **no** multiplicative transversal?

See here for some context: [Examples of non-free group actions on trees with finite edge-stabilizers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4101178/examples-of-non-free-group-actions-on-trees-with-finite-edge-stabilizers)

Any advice/insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question has a somewhat trivial answer: If you already had $\{g_1, g_2,... , g_n\}$ so that $G = g_1H \sqcup ... \sqcup g_nH$ forms a group and that $\{g_1, g_2,... , g_n\}$ **is** multiplicative, then you could replace $g_1$ by $g'_1=g_1 h$ for some nontrivial $h \in H$, and now you have $G = g'_1 H  \sqcup ... \sqcup g_nH$ forms a group and that $\{g'_1, g_2, ... , g_n\}$ is **not** multiplicative.

Comment: Are you hoping for a group $G$ where *no* transversal forms a multiplicative set, rather that for there to exist a transversal that is not multiplicative? Perhaps are you hoping for a group $G$ that is an extension of $H$ by a group of order $n$ but that does not split?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I would be interested in this case as well, yes

Comment: If that is what you want, then you should say so explicitly (in the post); make sure to indicate it is an addition so that Lee Mosher's comment doesn't seem like it missed the point. If that is not what you want, then you should not now add "Oh, that would be interesting."